# jQuery validate equalTo method : accessing the current element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to access the current element from the equalTo method?  In the code below, it works if I change it to

```
equalTo: "#" + $("#t2").parent().parent().find("input[name='thing1']").attr("id")
```

but I would rather not hard-code it.

I have searched stackoverflow and cannot find any answer that will help.

Note: I realize that this is not the best way to write this form. I cannot do anything about the naming scheme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- include jQuery and the validate plugin -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.validator.prototype.checkForm = function () {
            this.prepareForm();
            for (var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++) {
                if (this.findByName(elements[i].name).length != undefined && this.findByName(elements[i].name).length > 1) {
                    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName(elements[i].name).length; cnt++) {
                        this.check(this.findByName(elements[i].name)[cnt]);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.check(elements[i]);
                }
            }
            return this.valid();
        }

        $("#formthing").validate({
            rules: {
                thing1: "required",
                thing2: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#" + $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='thing1']").attr("id")
                }
            },
            messages: {
                thing1: "Please enter somthing",
                thing2: {
                    required: "Please repeat somthing",
                    equalTo: "Be sure it's equal"
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formthing" method="post" action="http://mcclurg.co/">
        <div>
            <div><label for="t1">Thing 1 </label><input type="text" name="thing1" id="t1" /></div>
            <div><label for="t2">Thing 2 </label><input type="text" name="thing2" id="t2" /></div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div>
            <div><label for="t3">Thing 1' </label><input type="text" name="thing1" id="t3" /></div>
            <div><label for="t4">Thing 2' </label><input type="text" name="thing2" id="t4" /></div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Stuff man" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new method. The method will receive the element, and you can perform the validation from there. Use this instead of the default `equalTo` method.

```
$.validator.addMethod("equalToPrevious", function(value, element) {
    if(value) {
        return $(element).val() === $(element).parent().parent().find("input[name='thing1']").val();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Be sure to modify the validation rules and messages.

```
$("#formthing").validate({
        rules: {
            thing1: "required",
            thing2: {
                required: true,
                equalToPrevious: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            thing1: "Please enter somthing",
            thing2: {
                required: "Please repeat somthing",
                equalToPrevious: "Be sure it's equal"
            }
        }
    });
```

This could be modified to have a value passed to it (like the name of the field you're looking for if you like).

Comment: Within your question and answer, it would be good to stress the point that you wrote a prototype to get around issues created by duplicating `name` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that you are duplicating your field names.  You have two fields named `thing1` and two fields named `thing2`.  The plugin is not going to be able to handle that well, especially since this plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of all input elements.

Simply giving everything a *unique* `name`, as mandated, is all that is needed.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/15s6x8pm/**

```
$("#formthing").validate({
    rules: {
        thing1: "required",
        thing2: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "thing1"
        },
        thing11: "required",
        thing22: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "thing11"
        }
    }, ....
```

Comment: I realize that this solution would be better. Due to constraints, I cannot change the names of the fields. The prototype that I added to the validator allows it to check multiple fields with the same name.